# Struggling With Understanding Scipy Optimize Minimize For Solving For Multiple Parameters

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, minimize

From the scipy minimize documentation:

> args : tuple, optional Extra arguments passed to the objective function and its derivatives

Great. And that's pretty much all it says about the `args` parameter.

So I have this code that produces a Holt-Winters forecast courtesy of [grisha.org](http://grisha.org/blog/2016/02/17/triple-exponential-smoothing-forecasting-part-iii/). In the blog post, the author determined that the optimal values for `alpha`, `beta` and `gamma` were `0.716`, `0.029`, `0.993` respectively.

I suspect I can use scipy's `minimize` function to solve for these three variables by minimizing the sum of squared errors.  That's what the `sse` function does below:

```
def sse(alpha, beta, gamma):
  pred = triple_exponential_smoothing(series, 12, alpha, beta, gamma, 24)
  return sum((pred[:series.shape[0]] - series)**2)
```

My problem is, my objective function `sse` takes three parameters (aka: multiple parameters).  What I want to be able to do is pass `sse` into `minimize` and let `minimize` tell me what the optimal values for `alpha`, `beta` and `gamma` are. All three parameters are bound between `0` and `1`. The "optimal" value will obviously be the three values that achieve the smallest `sse` value.

**Can this be achieved with `scipy.optimize.minimize`?**

```
minimize(sse, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], args=(beta, gamma),
         bounds=[(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)], method='SLSQP')
```

Here's my full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def initial_trend(series, slen):
  sum = 0.0
  for i in range(slen):
    sum += float(series[i+slen] - series[i]) / slen
  return sum / slen

def initial_seasonal_components(series, slen):
  seasonals = {}
  season_averages = []
  n_seasons = int(len(series)/slen)
  # compute season averages
  for j in range(n_seasons):
    season_averages.append(sum(series[slen*j:slen*j+slen])/float(slen))
  # compute initial values
  for i in range(slen):
    sum_of_vals_over_avg = 0.0
    for j in range(n_seasons):
      sum_of_vals_over_avg += series[slen*j+i]-season_averages[j]
    seasonals[i] = sum_of_vals_over_avg/n_seasons
  return seasonals

def triple_exponential_smoothing(series, slen, alpha, beta, gamma, n_preds):
  result = []
  seasonals = initial_seasonal_components(series, slen)
  for i in range(len(series)+n_preds):
    if i == 0: # initial values
      smooth = series[0]
      trend = initial_trend(series, slen)
      result.append(series[0])
      continue
    if i >= len(series): # we are forecasting
      m = len(series) - i + 1
      result.append((smooth + m*trend) + seasonals[i%slen])
    else:
      val = series[i]
      last_smooth, smooth = smooth, alpha*(val-seasonals[i%slen]) + (1-alpha)*(smooth+trend)
      trend = beta * (smooth-last_smooth) + (1-beta)*trend
      seasonals[i%slen] = gamma*(val-smooth) + (1-gamma)*seasonals[i%slen]
      result.append(smooth+trend+seasonals[i%slen])
  return np.array(result)

def sse(alpha, beta, gamma):
  pred = triple_exponential_smoothing(series, 12, alpha, beta, gamma, 24)
  return sum((pred[:series.shape[0]] - series)**2)

series = np.array([30,21,29,31,40,48,53,47,37,39,31,29,17,9,20,24,27,35,41,38,
          27,31,27,26,21,13,21,18,33,35,40,36,22,24,21,20,17,14,17,19,
          26,29,40,31,20,24,18,26,17,9,17,21,28,32,46,33,23,28,22,27,
          18,8,17,21,31,34,44,38,31,30,26,32])

#pred = triple_exponential_smoothing(series, 12, 0.716, 0.029, 0.993, 24)
pred = triple_exponential_smoothing(series, 12, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1, 24)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(pred, 'r:', label='Forecast')
ax.plot(series, 'k-', label='Actual', lw=1)
ax.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

**Before alpha, beta, gamma parameter optimization**

[image: Before alpha, beta, gamma parameter optimization]

**After alpha, beta, gamma parameter optimization**

[image: After alpha, beta, gamma parameter optimization]

Comment: `args` is for parameters that are constant w.r.t. your optimization. All parameters that are to be optimized go into a single vector. Your objective function operates on this vector. If it takes additional (constant) values, the `args` parameter will provide those values.

Comment: Thank you @cel. It clicked for me. I now realize that my objective function needs to accept a single parameter that could be a vector (a list for example) and in my function I need to reference the slice of that vector.

Comment: i know this is super old, but i am trying to do the exact same thing, where do you put ```minimize(sse, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], args=(beta, gamma),
         bounds=[(0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)], method='SLSQP')```. Did you put in inside of the mse function

Comment: `alpha, beta, gamma` became `x[0], x[1], x[2]` and `x` was passed as the first argument to `sse`. Inside `sse`, I called `triple_exponential_smoothing(...)` which accpeted `x[0], x[1], x[2]` for the `alpha, beta, gamma` function arguments.

Comment: thank you for your response, I still have a long way to go ^^